# "Google API Keys are Missing" error on latest version of Chromium after upgrade

Tags: google-api, chromium, api-key

For a while I've been using Chromium on my Windows 7 system and it's been working fine. However after upgrading to the latest version at the usual location of https://download-chromium.appspot.com, when I loaded the browser I get the message "Google API Keys are Missing. Some functionality of Chromium will be disabled".

I also can't then log into my Google Account, getting the message "Uh Oh. Service Unavailable, please try again later". I assume this happens because of the issue with the API keys above.

Despite removing, re-installing and going to the latest build today (362135) I still can't make the error go away. My normal version of Chrome works fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Oliver.